# How to Use multiple conditions in Xpath?

Tags: xpath

New to Xpath. Was trying in to use XML task in SSIS to load some values. Using Microsoft' XML inventory mentioned below.

How can I load first-name value in bookstore/books where style is novel and award = 'Pulitzer'?
`//book[@style='novel' and ./author/award/text()='Pulitzer']` is what I am trying. It gives the whole element. Where should I modify to just get the first-name value?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xsl" ?>
<bookstore specialty="novel">
  <book style="autobiography">
    <author>
      <first-name>Joe</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
    </author>
    <price>12</price>
  </book>
  <book style="textbook">
    <author>
      <first-name>Mary</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <publication>Selected Short Stories of
        <first-name>Mary</first-name>
        <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      </publication>
    </author>
    <editor>
      <first-name>Britney</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
    </editor>
    <price>55</price>
  </book>
  <magazine style="glossy" frequency="monthly">
    <price>2.50</price>
    <subscription price="24" per="year"/>
  </magazine>
  <book style="novel" id="myfave">
    <author>
      <first-name>Toni</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <degree from="Trenton U">B.A.</degree>
      <degree from="Harvard">Ph.D.</degree>
      <award>P</award>
      <publication>Still in Trenton</publication>
      <publication>Trenton Forever</publication>
    </author>
    <price intl="Canada" exchange="0.7">6.50</price>
    <excerpt>
      <p>It was a dark and stormy night.</p>
      <p>But then all nights in Trenton seem dark and
      stormy to someone who has gone through what
      <emph>I</emph> have.</p>
      <definition-list>
        <term>Trenton</term>
        <definition>misery</definition>
      </definition-list>
    </excerpt>
  </book>
  <my:book xmlns:my="uri:mynamespace" style="leather" price="29.50">
    <my:title>Who's Who in Trenton</my:title>
    <my:author>Robert Bob</my:author>
  </my:book>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got an answer.

```
//book[@style='novel' and ./author/award/text()='Pulitzer']//first-name
```

Comment: This is totally fine, there isn't anything to enhance.

Comment: I would not use `text()` unless I am dealing with mixed content (e.g. an XHTML `p` element containing `<p>The <b>quick</b> fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>`) and I explicitly need to select a text child or descendant (e.g. `/p/text()[1]` to select the text node with `The `). Otherwise I would simply compare the element. So in your case `//book[@style = 'novel' and author/award = 'Pulitzer']//first-name` suffices, you don't gain anything with using `author/award/text()`.

Comment: Thank you Jens and Martin for sharing your views.

Comment: [`Here`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) I don't get any such `and` operator, any reference where you got this?

Answer (score 5):

**Use**:

```
/*/book[@style='novel']/author[award = 'Pulitzer']/first-name
```

This selects any `first-name` element whose `author` parent has a `award` child with string value of 'Pulitzer' and whose (of the `author`) parent is a `book` whose `style` attribute has value "novel" and whose parent is the top element of the XML document.

Answer (score 1):

> A similar question in the same context. How can I do the vice-versa ? Let's suppose I want to find the id of all those books whose price is greater than 20 ? I know I am being a nudge, but really want to clear my understanding.

Here is the needed `XPATH` :

```
//book/price[text() > 20]/..
```